# How do I find and replace using Regular Expressions in Google Docs Text Editor?

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to import my notes from Kindle into a Google Doc (you can view it [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LG75VBG5JfW8V5NOKzzmdHw4Dbd3nR4aQB3uzLTVtIE/edit)), and I have a document in which I want to strip out all of the occurrences of the following text (including the line break):

> Read more at location 6567   • Delete this highlight
>   Add a note

I came up with the following search pattern and tested it on [this google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f4qGg4JiQZwVDW90fQjvc0CcehYnJf7GZONYKXBK5LM/edit#gid=0) to make sure my regex syntax works:

```
"Read more at location (\d*)   • Delete this highlight\nAdd a note"
```

Then I created a google apps script, and have it load in my document:

```
function onOpen() {
  DocumentApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('AdvancedFind&Replace')
      .addItem('Remove Kindle HTML', 'findAndReplace')
      .addToUi();
}

// In-Document Find and Replace

function findAndReplace() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
    body.replaceText("Read more at location (\d*)   • Delete this highlight\nAdd a note", "");
      }
```

However, when I run it, it doesn't replace the text. I think it's a problem with the REGEX, because when I run this code instead, it works:

```
function replaceBat() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
    body.replaceText("BBat", "BBAat REPLACEMENT SUCCESSFUL");
      }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#replaceText(String,String)), some patterns may not work:

> A subset of the JavaScript regular expression features are not fully
>   supported, such as capture groups and mode modifiers.

See [regex specifications in GoogleDocs here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en), it does not say that `\d` is supported. So, try this regex:

```
^Read more at location [0-9]* • Delete this highlight[[:space:]]Add a note
```

Or

```
^Read more at location [0-9]*[^[:alpha:]]*Delete this highlight[[:space:]]Add a note
```

Comment: Hi Wiktor,  That did not work for me, but this did:  ^Read more at location [0-9]*   • Delete this highlight[[:space:]]Add a note

Comment: That is strange. However, that means you can use POSIX character classes and the `*` quantifier. I updated the answer with your and my new suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that the Docs regex doesn't support "/d" for matching any digit or "/s" for matching any whitespace character, but it *does* support "[[:space:]]" for matching any whitespace character!

The following syntax worked in my document:

```
// In-Document Find and Replace

function findAndReplace() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  body.replaceText("^Read more at location [0-9]*   • Delete this highlight[[:space:]]Add a note", "");
      }
```

I found the [[:space:]] syntax at https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/postini/docs/admin/en/admin_ee_cu/cm_regex.html

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Google Docs & Sheets now allow you to natively use regular expressions when you search for text.

Simply open the native search functionality and you'll find the option to use regex.

[regex search functionality in google docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ff1ay.png)

you can find  more info here: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/62754

Answer (score 0):

A regex does not start and end with quotes; a string does. Your replace is looking for a literal string, not a regex.

Try:

```
body.replaceText(/Read more at location (\d*)   • Delete this highlight\nAdd a note/, "");
```

To get all instances, add the `g` flag:

```
body.replaceText(/Read more at location (\d*)   • Delete this highlight\nAdd a note/g, "");
```

Comment: Hi Mogsdad,  - not according to the documentation for the replaceText function:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replaceText(String,String)